# How to count rows in a table with two variables

Tags: r, count

I have a dataframe called dF with two columns: Name, Region. For instance,

```
Name Region
a    EU
a    EU
b    AM
C    AP
...  ...
```

If I do table(dF), it will show a table with two variables. For instance like this

```
'table' int [1:325,1:3]

        Region
Name    EU  AM  AP
a       2   0   0
b       0   1   0
c       0   0   1
```

How do I count the number of rows for only specific variables? For instance, just getting how many times the number three appears for the AM Region variable in the table column.

Comment: why don't you save the results from table as a `data.frame` and then use `subset(df,AM==3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

```
result <- table(state.division, state.region)  #Sample data 
result #will return data like shown below

        state.region
state.division       Northeast South North Central West
  New England                6     0             0    0
  Middle Atlantic            3     0             0    0
  South Atlantic             0     8             0    0
  East South Central         0     4             0    0
  West South Central         0     4             0    0
  East North Central         0     0             5    0
  West North Central         0     0             7    0
  Mountain                   0     0             0    8
  Pacific                    0     0             0    5

  sum(result[,2]==4) #to count 4's in second column
```

So in your case you need to store the resulting table to a variable, and the following should do it:

```
result <- table(dF)
sum(result[,2]==3)
```